# Fisher-Yates Shuffle in a Listbox? C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, listbox, shuffle

I have a form that contains a listbox and four radio buttons.  Each radio button adds a certain amount of numbers to the listbox (100, 1,000, 10,000, and 100,000).  I am attempting to apply the Fisher-Yates Shuffle Algorithm to ensure there are no duplicate numbers in the array.  I've tried everything that has been suggested online and not much is helping.  When I run my code below, the listbox just displays a bunch of zeroes, instead of numbers 1-100 that are shuffled.  Is there something I am missing or something that I am doing wrong?

```
private void randNumGenerator(int Size)
    {
        Numbers.Items.Clear();
        array = new int[Size];

        Shuffle(array);

        foreach(int value in array)
        {
            Numbers.Items.Add(value);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Shuffle Algorithm
    static Random numGenerator = new Random();
    static void Shuffle(int[] array)
    {
        for (int i = array.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            int r = numGenerator.Next(0, i);
            int temp = array[r];
            array[r] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: `array = new int[Size]; Shuffle(array);` you send an array of zeros to shuffle here. displayed result is correct. try use `for` loop to fill array with numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the line:

```
array = new int[Size];
```

To:

```
array = Enumerable.Range(0, Size).ToArray();
```